# FLS check in 2GP

Tags: apex, managed-package, security, fls, 2gp

I've created a new 2GP package. Since it is going to be released to AppExchange, I've implemented a generic CRUD and FLS check for every place I contact with the Database in my Apex code.

e.g.

```
MyAwsomeObject.getDescribe().isUpdateable();
MyAwesomeField.getDescribe().isUpdateable();
```

I build a new package version with `-c` key for Apex test coverage, but the tests fail due to FLS permission checks. CRUD checks pass just fine.

From the documentation, 2GP build goes this way:

1. A new inaccessible scratch org is created.
2. Metadata is pushed to the scratch org.
3. Tests run.
4. The post-install script runs.

So I don't see a way to assign FLS permissions to the user on behalf of who the tests are running.

Building a package without `-c` or without FLS checks works perfectly.

Is there a way to overcome this FLS check, give FLS access to the running user or any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in Apex Tests, you can use the [RunAs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) feature to do this - basically, create a user in the test, assign a basic profile (the new [Minimum Access](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_new_profile.htm) one is helpful for this), and then assign the permission set, and run the test e.g.

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Minimum Access - Salesforce '];

User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email = 'standarduser@bfcclient.com',
EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', LastName = 'Testing', LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', UserName = 'standarduser@bfcclient.com');

insert u;

PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'My Permission Set'];
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = u.id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id);
```

But - this assumes you are including the Perm Set in the package. If not, you'll probably need to wait for [this new feature](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_path_unpackaged_md.htm) (or apply to pilot) which will let you include non=packaged metadata in the package creation process when it builds the scratch org.

Comment: I feel stupid to not thinking about that option. Yes, I have permission set in the package. Thank you, I'll try it!